# DevExpress Wpf Scheduler theme

Tags: wpf, devexpress, themes, scheduler

Hi I am new to DevExpress as well as Wpf, I would like to know if there is any way by which I can customize the look of the Wpf Scheduler control? Either changing the theme or creating and applying custom theme is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [`ThemeManager.ThemeName`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreThemeManager_ThemeNametopic) attached property.

For `Window`:

```
<Window
    ... 
    dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Black"> 
    <Grid> 
        ...
        <dxsch:SchedulerControl ... >
        </dxsch:SchedulerControl>
        ...
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

For `Scheduler` itself:

```
<dxsch:SchedulerControl ... dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2007Black">
</dxsch:SchedulerControl>
```

In code:

```cs
ThemeManager.SetTheme(schedulerControl1, new Theme("Metropolis Dark"));
```

You can use [predefined themes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7407) or create your own.

Comment: I am using older version of DevExprees (DevExpress 2010.2), I cannot find some of the themes which are present in v 14.1. Is there any way by which I can use the themes which are come along with v14?

Comment: @user1650891 I have no idea. Try to ask this question to DevExpress Support. Maybe they can help you.